# How correctly make REST API request to get complete orders between a date range in Magento 2

Tags: rest, magento2

I want to get complete orders between a date range using Magento 2 REST Api. So request looks like:

```
/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=Complete&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

Now I want get it in specific period. I found that Magento api has "from" and "to" fields but  I always confused in searchCriteria filter index. Can anybody complete my request? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You will get complete orders between a date range by using the conditions `from` and `to`.

This API will get you the orders between the two dates:

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=from_date&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=to_date
```

Example:

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=from&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2016-07-01 00:00:00&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=to&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2018-07-01 00:00:00
```

The above API will get you the orders between a by using `created_at` timestamp.

For an example also see the [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/performing-searches.html#logical-and-and-or-search).